# Awesome & youtube

Tags: ubuntu, awesome, youtube

I run Awesome WM on Ubuntu.

Recently when I try to watch youtube videos in full screen they have been playing in a small letter box - They have not 'full screened'.

In the other hand, Vimeo & Dailymotion videos work correctly.

NOTICE! This is NOT the problem of a youtube video appearing 'behind' the browser. I already have that fix in my rc.lua:

```
 -- Fix for youtube fullscreen in chrome:
{
  rule = {
    instance = "exe"
  },
  properties = { floating = true }
},
```

This applies to Chrome and Firefox.

How can I fix the issue so I can view youtube videos in full screen mode again?

Comment: Are you using awesome in tiling more?  Could you try with a different layout just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to stumble upon this issue from time to time. Usually, I simply maximize the (small) player window using `mod + M` while the video is playing. Although this is only a workaround and does not fix the issue (it never annoyed me enough to dig deeper).

Comment: mod + M doesn't improve things for me

Comment: @andyboot How so? Does [Mod4 + f](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/manpages/awesome.1.html) work for you to toggle fullscreen? (You'll have to scroll down a bit to the "Default Key Bindings" section in the link.)

Comment: mod4+f does toggle fullscreen. and mod+m does maximize [at least for all the other applications]  but the youtube video doesn't get any bigger.

Comment: Does it work correctly when you use floating mode before starting fullscreen from the player (if not already tried)?

Comment: nice idea but no. I just tried.